# Parsing a date string in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, date

My son is learning C++ and one of his exercises it to have the user input a date in DD/MM/YYY and then output it to Month day, year

```
So: 19/02/2013
Output: February 19, 2013.
```

I am trying to help him understand the various ways but now I have confused myself.

`getline()`
`std::string::substr()`
`std::string::find()`
`std::string::find_first_of()`
`std::string::find_last_of()`

I can't figure it out with any of these quite right.

my current attempt to parse is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    string date;
    string line;

    cout << "Enter a date in dd/mm/yyyy format: " << endl;
    std::getline (std::cin,date);

    while (getline(date, line))
    {
        string day, month, year;
        istringstream liness( line );
        getline( liness, day, '/' );
        getline( liness, month,  '/' );
        getline( liness, year,   '/' );

        cout << "Date pieces are: " << day << " " << month << " " << year << endl;
    }
}
```

but I am getting errors like:

```
`g++ 3_12.cpp -o 3_12`
`3_12.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
`3_12.cpp:16: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’`
`3_12.cpp:18: error: variable ‘std::istringstream liness’ has initializer but incomplete type`
```

Comment: You're not doing your kid any favors doing his work for him.

Comment: Thanks Austin, but he is here sitting next to me looking at docs to figure this out too. So I call it teamwork

Comment: And might I add that this is his week off from school so also extracurricular.

Comment: `size_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)` is a [POSIX function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html). I don't think trying to call it  was your intent, or was it?

Comment: We are on OS X, using G++

Comment: @AustinMullins Sitting with your children doing work together is a great pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int day, month, year;
char t;
std::cin >> day >> t >> month >> t >> year;
```

Comment: isnt that an interesting way!

Comment: @Jason I would consider it the only (out of the one presented) way :/, regex is OVERKILL as are `std::string`s and `std::getline`

Comment: Regex you get validation for free. `std::string` is free in most implementation due to short string optimisation.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain for free in what context, it's certainly not computationally cheap. and the complexity of a good regex can easier be mocked up in code.

Comment: Quite frankly, we're not talking low latency bit twiddling hacks here, rather general programming advice for a young programmer. The C++ idiom for strings is `std::string`, which is near on free in most cases. Regex-s are incredibly powerful for many problems and this is a great application.

Comment: sure, so this solution should be fine then. Further more the OP has indicated they use g++ which has not implemented <regex>, even IF they are using the newest version.

Comment: @111111 This surely works for this exercise. I think that this great.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the [`std` Regular Expressions Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)! I reckon it's the safest and most effective way of doing this.

Back on topic, I *think* that since `getline` is an `extern "C"` function, you can't overload it using a `using namespace std` (which should be banned by the way). You should try prepending `std` to all `getline` calls.

Comment: good point about `using namespace std;` This was my quick attempt. Hw does do it the better way of `std::` for everything

Answer (score 1):

For `std::istringstream`, you need:

```
#include <sstream>
```

P.S. Don't use `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit, and it will eventually get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> `3_12.cpp:16: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’`

means the compiler couldn't make sense of this line:

```
while (getline(date, line))
```

Both `date` and `line` are declared as `std::string` and there's no overload of `getline` that
takes two strings. Compiler guessed that you were trying to call [this function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html) that is not part of C++ library (apparently, one of standard library headers includes `stdio.h` which is where that function is coming from).

The error

> `3_12.cpp:18: error: variable ‘std::istringstream liness’ has initializer but incomplete type`

means the compiler doesn't know what `std::istringstream` is. You forgot to include `<sstream>`.

If you want to extract lines from a string by means of `std::getline`, you need to put it in a stringstream first, just like you do inside the loop.

Parsing dates isn't that easy. You don't want the user to be able to enter `44/33/-200` and get away with it. How I'd might approach this:

```
std::istringstream iss(date); // date is the line you got from the user

unsigned int day, month, year;
char c1, c2;

if (!(iss >> day >> c1 >> month >> c2 >> year)) {
    // error
}
if (c1 != '/' || c2 != '/') { /* error */ }
if (month > 12) { /* error  / }

// ... more of that, you get the idea
```